# Dirichlet convolution of completely multiplicative functions

Tags: number-theory

An arithmetic function $f: \mathbb{N}_0 \to \mathbb{C}$ is said to be completely multiplicative if $f(mn)=f(m)f(n)$, for all $m,n \geq 0$. The Dirichlet convolution of two arithmetic functions $f,g$ is defined as:

$$(f \ast g)(n)= \sum_{mm'=n}f(m)g(m').$$

Is the Dirichlet convolution of two completely multiplicative arithmetic functions necessarily completely multiplicative?

Comment: No it's not! Try $(f*g)(4)$.

Comment: I obtain that $f(2k)=0$, or $g(2k)=0$, for all $k \geq 1$. How does this imply a contradiction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is completely multiplicative iff $f(p)g(p)=0$ for all $p$. Completely multiplicative means $$\sum_n h(n)n^{-s}=\prod_p \frac1{1-h(p)p^{-s}}$$

Comment: Do you know any explicit counterexamples?

Comment: $f=g=1{}{}{}{}$